# Salesforce1 app crashes when back button is pressed

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, custom-object

I have created a Salesforce1 app(android) which has only visualforce pages. The problems I have been facing is

1. When I press back button from a vf page, the app closes
2. When I try to upload an image, the page refreshes and all the entries are lost.

After going through some online resources. I have come up with the following code

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'/>
<script src="https://mobile1.t.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script>
function myUpdate()
{
var accountId = document.getElementById('accountId').value;

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
'{!$RemoteAction.StandardController.StandardController}', accountId, function(result, event)
{
if(result!=null) sforce.one.navigateToSObject(result,"detail"); 
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});

});
}
</script>

<input id="photoFile" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
<a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="myUpdate()">Save</a>
```

This is how my standard controller APEX Class looks like

```
public with sharing class StandardController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController standardController { get; set; }
    public StandardController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }
}
```

[image: No remoted actions found to resolve]